# How to check if a volume is currently unlocked OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to check the state of a volume drive to see whether its locked or unlocked via terminal. how would i go around doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple commands that I know of.

`GetFileInfo` shows a locked attribute... for example:

`GetFileInfo -al /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` will print out `0` (the `l` after the `-a` attribute parameter means `locked` and the return of `0` means false).  It doesn't seem foolproof though, because I'll still see a `0` (false) return even for locked DMG files.

In a shell script, this might be something like:

```
output=$(GetFileInfo -al /Volumes/Untitled )
if [ $output -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo "locked"
  else
    echo "unlocked"
fi
```

Also, there's `diskutil`. If you do `diskutil info /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` you'll see a result of:

`Read-Only Media:          No
 Read-Only Volume:         No`

or, on a read-only DMG, you might see:

`Read-Only Media:          Yes
 Read-Only Volume:         Yes`

I'm not sure if these answers are the ones you are looking for, but hopefully that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, this helps alot. i was wondering if there is a way to made a conditional statement based on this? for example.. if volume is locked echo locked else echo unlocked?

Comment: I just added a shell script example, but there must be is certainly a way to do it all on one line, too.  It's a little too early for my brain to operate properly to figure that one liner out.